# Prove $d\left( ab\right) \geq d\left( a\right) +d\left( b\right) -7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I prove that $d\left( ab\right) \geq d\left( a\right) +d\left( b\right) -7$?

Here, $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: FYI: $d(ab) \le d(a)+d(b)$ is not always true. For example, If $a = b = 6$, then, $d(ab) = d(36) = 9$ while $d(a)+d(b) = d(6)+d(6) = 4+4 = 8$.

Comment: I see. I thought maybe some common divisors would cancel out. But you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove something stronger. In fact: $$d(n)\geq d(a)+d(b)-1.$$
To do this, let $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_n$ be the prime factors of either $a$ or $b$. We can write $$a=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_n^{\alpha_n},$$ $$b=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\ldots p_n^{\beta_n},$$ so that $\alpha_i\geq0$, $\beta_i\geq0$, for all $i$. By using the formula for the number of divisors of a number, what we want to prove is equivalent to $$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\alpha_i+\beta_i+1\right)\geq \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\alpha_i+1\right)+\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\beta_i+1\right)-1.$$ However, when we expand this out, it's easy to see that every summand on the RHS will appear too on the LHS, except for the $1$'s, which cancel out anyway. Since every summand is non-negative, this is enough to prove our inequality.

Comment: Hi, don't really get why a and b are only factored into p1,...,pn. If these are common for a and b, surely both a and b would have other prime divisors that are not common between them.

Comment: My mistake. It’s not the common prime factors, but instead those that divide either. I’ve edited my solution.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Shouldnt it be something like that:
a=p1^alpha1*...*pk^alphak*...*pn^alphan
b=p1^beta1^*...*pk^betak*qm^betam*...qt^betat
. Sorry, cant format at the moment. I'm trying to say that p1 to pk are common prime divisors, then pk+1 to pn are exclusive to a and qm to qt are exclusive to b.

Comment: You could also write it like that, but since we don't care if the exponents are zero in this case, just taking all the relevant prime factors works. Plus, it makes it easier to write down the formulas.